# Iphone doesn't work in background mode if it is locked

Tags: ios, iphone

Well, I have an app and a server request inside it, which sends me a big zip archive for several minutes as a response. The request immediately returns code 200 and has

**Status: receiving response body...**

until the archive is entirely downloaded. If during this process I go to the background with the home button - everything will be OK, the app will continue downloading the archive.

But if I press the power button and lock an iPhone - the downloading will immediately stop and the request returns in addition

**Failure: Client closed connection before receiving entire response**

What's the reason of such behaviour? Is there any differences between these background modes? (by the way, application states hierarchy is the same in both variants) Is iPhone allowed to work in background while it's locked? If not, is there any way to allow it to do this? 
This problem occurs both with iOS 8.x and iOS 7.x

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a passcode lock on the device? Try removing it and see if you still have the same issue.

Comment: No, I don't have any passcode or other restrictions for device locking.